# How to match the input field with the data inside the column database using PHP Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, laravel

I have one input field named "policy_no". So from this group, I want to select the column that consist any of the input. The input might be "12345 12346 12347". I already put the LIKE statement inside the sql but still it select all column. It seems doesn't recognize which column that consist of the policy no, since I input several policy_no at one time. So, how do I select the database from that? Or should I substring the input field?

This is my view.blade.php

```
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Policy No</label>
                    <textarea name="policy_no" value="$items->policy_no" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
```

This is my controller.

```
public function Exported(Request $request) {

        $item = InsuranceEnrollment::find($request->policy_no);

        $policy_no = $request->get('policy_no');

        $group1 = $request->get('group');

       if (InsuranceEnrollment::where('policy_no', 'LIKE','%". $policy_no ."%')->where('insurance_enrollments.exported', '=', '0')->exists()) {
           $item = DB::table('insurance_enrollments')->update(['exported' => 1, 'group' => $group1]);
       }

        \Session::flash('message', 'The policy number is successfully exported');
        return redirect()->route('admin-insurance.sales');
    }
```

Comment: are you always using a blank space to seperate different policy numbers `12345 7865, 67976` ??

Comment: Yup, I have to separate them. @prakashchhetri

Answer (score 1):

If you are always using a white space to seperate the numbers, I belive you could just seperate the input string based on the white space using `explode()`.

You can then use `whereIn` to fetch all the policy items which match the ID's in the exploded array.

```
public function Exported(Request $request) {
        $policyNumbers = explode ( ' ' , $request->policy_no);
        $items = InsuranceEnrollment::whereIn('policy_no', $policyNumbers)->get();    
}
```

Comment: It's not work. It still select all other policy no that doesn't exist in the input column.